# leaflet is loading html inside script tag

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I found this very weird situation when using leaflet.js library on my local server:

the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>map lab</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
        <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
        <style type='text/css'>
            #map { height: 256px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var map = new L.map('map').setView([0.0, 0.0], 14);
            L.tileLayer('http://10.21.142.254/lab/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>'
            }).addTo(map); 

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just fine but nothing 'loads'. When inspecting on FF using Firebug i found that the whole 'html' is inserted inside the script tag (line 7). I.e. the whole htm and the  with the leaflet code is inside there and the console returns (obviously) a Syntax Error.

Downloaded leaflet from Github and tried all types of placing that on my directory structure but no result.

Besides, loading the leaflet library from their server using:

```
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4/leaflet.js"></script>
```

works great so far.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. My mistake. Somehow setting the links using absolute path URL instead of relative solves this issue.

instead of:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
<script src="leaflet.js"></script>`

use:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.domain.com/lab/js/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://www.domain.com/lab/js/leaflet.js"></script>`

thx.